# Angular map http response value with another http call

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, httpclient

I have an http call that looks like this :

```
public getCommuneByCode(code: string): Observable<Commune> {
  return this.http.get<Commune[]>(ApiUrl);
}
```

And the the Commune model as follow :

```
export interface Commune {
  code: string;
  departement: string;
  postalCode: string;
}
```

I have another http call to get a user data :

```
public getUserData(id: number): Observable<User> {
  return this.http.get<User>(ApiUrl);
}
```

User model :

```
export interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  libAddress: string;
}
```

Want I to do is to set the libAddress property with the response of the getCommuneByCode service like this :

```
this.service.getUserData(id).pipe(
    map((user: User) => {
      user.libAddress = this.service.getCommuneByCode(code).pipe(
        map(commune => `${commune.postalCode} - ${commune.departement}`)
      );
      return user;
    })
  ).subscribe((userWithLibAddress) => {
    // user object with all data and libAddress property is equal to ex: 99999 - DepartementXX
  })
```

But as I expected it's returning an observable of the answer and I'm not sure how to do it to get the answer. Thank for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one should work. If you need explanation, ask for it !

```
forkJoin(
  this.service.getUserData(id),
  this.service.getCommuneByCode(code)
).pipe(
  map(([user, commune]) => ({ ...user, libAdress: `${commune.postalCode} - ${commune.departement}`})
);
```

**EDIT** If you have to make the calls in sequence :

```
this.service.getUserData(id).pipe(
  switchMap(user => this.service.getCommuneByCode(user.code)).pipe(
    map(commune => ({ ...user, libAdress: `${commune.postalCode} - ${commune.departement}`}))
  )
)
```

Comment: I thought about forkjoin, but the problem is that if getCommuneByCode fail for any reason both of them fail, which is not what I want.

Comment: Even without `forkJoin`, if you have an error then your code won't work. That's the principle of errors, they don't do what you expect. That's why you have operators like `catchError`, to process errors when they appear. You argument doesn't really add up there, and is sure not a reason to downvote : your question was about composing an object, not about how to manage errors.

Comment: I didn't downvote I was surprised like you when I saw it, I like your solution and so I had no reason to down vote. And thank for you answer concerning catchError, in fact it will be handled in the same way with whatever operator I use

Comment: Okay, my bad then ! And that's right, you will need the `catchError` any way. In my opinion, `forkJoin` is way cleaner than using `[merge/switch/concat]Map` operators, since they will add an indent level and will produce the same result.

Comment: Oh my bad I do remember now why I couldn't use forkJoin actually, I forget to specify my fault, by the code to call the getCommuneByCode service is based on the user service response. I tried to simplify my api for the question but I missed this detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MergeMap. For example you can try something like this-

```
this.service.getUserData(id).pipe(
    mergeMap( (user:User) => this.service.getCommuneByCode(code).pipe(
        map(commune => user.libAddress = `${commune.postalCode} - ${commune.departement}`)
      )
    )
  ).subscribe();
```